# How to create dynamic groups in azure ad through powershell?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory

I'm trying to create dynamic groups in azure ad using below powershell command:

```
New-AzureADMSGroup -DisplayName "us_demo_group" -Description "This group contains information of users from us domain" -MailEnabled $False -MailNickName "group" -SecurityEnabled $True -GroupTypes "DynamicMembership" -membershipRule "(user.department -contains ""Marketing"")" -membershipRuleProcessingState "On"
```

Reference link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/new-azureadmsgroup?view=azureadps-2.

While executing this command I get below error :

```
> New-AzureADMSGroup : A parameter cannot be found that matches
> parameter name 'membershipRule'.
```

I have imported both the azureAD and azureADPrewview modules.
I have global administartor role and Azure AD Premium P2 set up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ensure you're using the [AzureADPreview](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/AzureADPreview/2.0.2.102) and not the [AzureAD](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/AzureAD/2.0.2.76).

In case you have both installed open a new powershell window and import the preview one like this:

```
Import-Module AzureADPreview
```

Answer (score 0):

if you still getting the error then remove the AzureAD module first and then import azureADpreview

```
Remove-Module AzureAD -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

Import-Module AzureADPreview
```